# ImportError at /home/, No module named home.urls

Tags: python, django, importerror

Python 2.7 + Django 1.7

I'm getting:

```
Page not found (404)
Request Method:     GET
Request URL:    http://localhost:8000/home/

Using the URLconf defined in home.urls, Django tried these URL patterns, in this order:

^(?P<pk>\d+)/home/$ [name='home']
^(?P<pk>\d+)/services/$ [name='services']
^(?P<pk>\d+)/contact/$ [name='contact']

The current URL, home/, didn't match any of these.

You're seeing this error because you have DEBUG = True in your Django settings file. Change that to False, and Django will display a standard 404 page.
```

home/urls.py:

```
from django.conf.urls import patterns, include, url
from django.contrib import admin

from home import views

urlpatterns = patterns('', 
    url(r'^(?P<pk>\d+)/home/$', views.Home(), name='home'),
    url(r'^(?P<pk>\d+)/services/$', views.Services(), name='services'),
    url(r'^(?P<pk>\d+)/contact/$', views.Contact(), name='contact')
)
```

mysite/urls.py:

```
from django.conf import settings
from django.conf.urls.static import static

from django.conf.urls import patterns, include, url

from django.contrib import admin

admin.autodiscover()

urlpatterns = patterns('',
    url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),
    url(r'^home/', include('mysite.home.urls', namespace="home")),
    url(r'^services/', include('home.urls', namespace="services")),
    url(r'^contact/', include('home.urls', namespace="contact"))
)
```

Why is this?

Project structure:

```
sitename
    db.sqlite3
    home
        __init.py
        admin.py
        models.py
        static
            home.html
            services.html
            contact.html
        urls.py
        views.py
    manage.py
    mysite
        __init.py
        settings.py
        urls.py
        wsgi.py
```

This doesn't include some pyc or pycache files. (I need to add more details to edit so I guess I'll just add some more text. Maybe this is what it wants. I don't know.)

Comment: Why do you think that `home/` should match one of those patterns?

Comment: As @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams suggests, none of your patterns will match that url. What will happen when you to go `http://localhost/home` is that it will just include your `mysite.home.urls` file and then find no matching pattern for what's left (which is an empty string). In your `home/urls.py` file, you should add a match for `r'^$'` and have it return a view.

Comment: I thought using url(r'^(?P<pk>\d+)/home/$', views.Home(), name='home') did this. What am I missing?

Comment: Need more info, what does your project's directory structure look like? Could you add  that to the question?

Comment: I tried removing the ^ in the urlconf, but no dice.

Comment: @11119 `localhost:8000/home/` never would match with your url rule `url(r'^(?P<pk>\d+)/home/$', views.Home(), name='home')`. With your actual urls rules, you could match `/home/112312/home`  .

Comment: Levi- the end result needs to be www.sitename.com/home. What do I need to do to make this happen?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

home/urls.py:

```
from django.conf.urls import patterns, include, url
from django.contrib import admin

from home import views

urlpatterns = patterns('', 
    url(r'^home/$', views.Home(), name='home'),
    url(r'^services/$', views.Services(), name='services'),
    url(r'^contact/$', views.Contact(), name='contact')
)
```

mysite/urls.py:

```
from django.conf import settings
from django.conf.urls.static import static

from django.conf.urls import patterns, include, url

from django.contrib import admin

admin.autodiscover()

urlpatterns = patterns('',
    url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),
    url(r'^', include('home.urls', namespace='mysite')),
)
```

I'm not sure if you actually want a `pk` for your home app, but if you do just change your root urlconf to this instead.

```
url(r'^(?P<pk>\d+)/', include('home.urls', namespace='mysite')),
```

You can catch up on the urlconf documentation here: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/topics/http/urls/#including-other-urlconfs

Comment: I'm not sure that I need a pk. I just want a simple way to view the website's homepage from www.localhost/8000/home so I can refresh it while I change the template. The code I've used is from various tutorials, some of it is probably cumbersome and unnecessary. Do you think using a pk is a good idea?

Comment: It's for database stuff mostly, so no.

Answer (score 1):

Expanding on the comments from @Ngenator, your url patterns in your main urls.py file route everything to a url structure preceded by:

- admin
- home
- services
- contact

and reading into/ guessing what you are trying to do, you probably don't need:

```
(?P<pk>\d+)
```

You would use that when you wanted to grab that parameter pk in a views.py file like:

```
def my_view(request, pk):
```

Therefore, my guess is that you could have your url patterns defined in that one mysite/urls.py folder.

In my opinion it would not make sense to define services and contact in your home/urls.py file.  You'd probably only need all of those other namespaces if you actually had apps for home, contacts, admin, etc.

Does that make sense?  You don't need a urls.py defined for every single app.  If you wanted to keep the urls.py structure for home/urls.py while maintaining a url structure like http://localhost.com:8000/home/, then in your home/urls.py you could just do something like:

```
url(r'^', home.views.Home(), name='home'),
```

under the assumption that your home/views.py file has a function like:

```
def Home(request):
```

Comment: So every different page on the website needs its own app?

Comment: No, quite the opposite.  Every page needs a url and a view assigned to it.  One app can have multiple pages by having multiple functions defined in the views.py file.  Urls can be defined in that apps urls.py file or in the mysite/urls.py file.  Does that make sense?

Comment: That does make sense. So, I should define all my urls in mysite.urls and import those urls into views.py? I don't really need home.urls?

Comment: For your app that should be fine.  Eventually, as the app becomes more complex it is probably more appropriate to create an app for home, services, and contact.  However, you could for instance define in home/views.py a def Services(request): , def Admin(request): etc as Ngenator put in his code snippet.

Comment: This makes much more sense. Thank you.